# Как подгружать в шаблон текст?

Tags: html, css, запрос, веб-программирование

Всем привет!
Есть n-ое количество подстраниц сайта, все одинаковые по оформлению, разница только в тексте. Как сделать так, чтобы был единый шаблон и в него подружался в зависимости от страницы нужный текст? Заранее спасибо за советы

Comment: возьмите какую-нибудь CMS, натяните на нее шаблон и радуйтесь создавая только разные страницы в админке с нужными текстами

Comment: Спасибо! А если без CMS? Jquery аль еще чего

Comment: я бы сделал "в лоб" на php